# How get last n month of data for each ID from 2 tables using SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables, A and B. I want to have last 3 months of Db_date (table B) from the Start_Date (tableA) for each ID.

**Table A**

| ID | Start_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-01 |

**Table B**

| ID | Start_Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-01 | 1000 |
| 1 | 2022-07-01 | 2000 |
| 1 | 2022-06-01 | 3000 |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 | 500 |

I know by using below code can get last 3 months from the current moth of Start_Date, but I want have last 3 months of Db_Date Amount from table B, for each Start_Date for each ID in Table A.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TableA
 WHERE Start_Date >= DATEADD(M, -3, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `outer apply` to get the sum of amount the last three months from `TableB`

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA a
OUTER APPLY(SELECT SUM(Amount) as SumAmountFor3MonthsAfterStart
  FROM TableB 
  WHERE StartDate > DATEADD(M, -3, a.Start_Date)
) OA
WHERE Start_Date >= DATEADD(M, -3, GETDATE())
```